# What is the most common word in Japanese?

Tags: words

What is the most common word in Japanese?

Answer (score 6):

The most common word, according to pretty much all the frequency lists I've found, is:

### する

Although if you count particles and auxiliaries, then **の** is probably the most common.

Sources:

- [Frequency list 1](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists/Japanese)
- [Frequency list 2](http://www.manythings.org/japanese/words/leeds/)
- [Frequency list 3](http://shang.kapsi.fi/kanji/jawp-mecab-words.csv)
- [Frequency list 4](http://ftp.monash.edu.au/pub/nihongo/wordfreq_ck.gz)

Comment: I'm surprised to see ぬ in the top 50. Where does it come from...

Comment: not うん…?! Unbelievable.

Comment: This seems strange to me. It's like saying "... although if you count articles and prepositions, then **the** is probably the most common." for English. Particles, auxiliaries, prepositions, and articles are just kinds of words. Then again the OP didn't specify.

Comment: @hippietrail It depends on your theory of grammar.  Do you consider 及ばない one word or two?  Is 私の one word or two?  The truth is, "word" isn't well-defined.

Comment: @snailboat: That is certainly true, which is why an answer shouldn't be based on one arbitrarily chosen definition of "word". At least you hedged your bets and gave both answers though (-: